# Pass parameter string in URL similar to -d CURL command

Tags: rest, curl, localhost

Very basic question about `curl`:

I can successfully pass a string parameter to the application exposing REST API on localhost with:

```
curl -d "stringParam = a b c d" 'localhost:8080/jobs?appName=testApp'
```

How would I compose regular URL that can be entered in a browser? I've tried:

```
localhost:8080/jobs?appName=testApp&stringParam="a b c d"
```

, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With cURL, when you use the `-d` switch, it will automatically turn it in to a POST request with the data (-d) as the entity body. What you are trying to do with the browser is send it in the URL (via implicit GET), which is not the same. In the the URL, it is a query parameter. What you are doing in the browser is the same as if you were to send the cURL request to that same URL (as you are with the Browser), without the `-d` switch. That will send a default GET, just like the browser.

If you want to do browser work, I'd suggest installing a browser extenstion, like [Postman for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) or [Rest Client for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/), or [Advanced Rest Client for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo). There you can POST data to your REST services.